# how can I download config.xml files for all the jobs under a folder on Jenkins by using curl. I can download a single file but I need all of them

Tags: xml, curl, jenkins

Is there a way Curl can grep all the config files under a job and place it locally on my system?

I can use the following to download a single file:

```
curl -k https://username:password/Jenkins/Folder/job/config.xml -o test.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below script to download `config.xml`:

```
#!/bin/bash
joblist=( job1 job2 job3) ## list of job

for i in "${joblist[@]}"
  do
    curl --user username:password https:///Jenkinsurl/Folder/$i/config.xml -o $i.xml
  done
```

Comment: Thanks Pratik. If I do as you suggested then I only get one config.xml that has all the jobs name but not the corresponding config file for those.

Comment: you need to specify in the list "joblist=( job1 job2 job3)"

Comment: The script worked but the syntax of the curl command was a little different that I had to try. Thank you for your help!!